# No definition for VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL in Vulkan.hpp?

Tags: vulkan

The Vulkan.hpp seems to have an equivalent for everything in the C header file except for this. Am I missing something? Are there other discrepancies?

https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#windows

I'm using version Vulkan Khronos SDK, 1.0.54.0

This one specifically
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp

Comment: Which "vulkan.hpp" are you referring to?

Comment: The one provided by the Vulkan SDK in the link I just edited in. It includes the binaries for the Vulkan library and headers. Like Vulkan.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined by `vulkan.h`, which is [included by `vulkan.hpp`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/master/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp). It's just a constant; it's not an enumerator. So it doesn't get any C++-isms.

Neither do any of the other constants like `VK_MAX_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_NAME_SIZE` and `VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE`. The C++ header is not meant to be stand-alone.

Comment: Thanks so is it just constants then?